# Error in TYPE IS specification when using gfortran-9 (but not gfortran 7)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

When updating my compiler from gfortran version 7.5 to version 9.3.0 my code no longer compiles. The following is a minimal test case:

```
program TypeIsTest
    implicit none
    integer :: i
    real(kind(1d0)) :: d

    i = 0
    d = 0.d0
    call TypeWriter(i)
    call TypeWriter(d)

contains

    subroutine TypeWriter(x)
        class(*), intent(in) :: x
        select type(x)
            type is(integer)
                write(*,*) "The type is integer"
            type is(real(kind(1d0)))
                write(*,*) "type is real*8"
        end select
    end subroutine TypeWriter
end program
```

in gfortran 7.5 this compiles whithout issue and results in the expected output, but in gfortran-9 i get this error:

```
TypeIsTest.f90:18:46:

    18 |                         type is(real(kind(1d0)))
       |                                              1
Error: Syntax error in TYPE IS specification at (1)
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong here. A collegue who has gfortran 9 on a macbook does not get this error, so I am thinking that maybe there are other parts of the system that are outdated, but updating and upgrading with apt reveals that everything is up to date.

Comment: Code looks fine. As a work-around it seems you can use a named constant `integer, parameter :: rk=kind(1d0); ...; type is (real(rk))` in the subroutine.

Comment: "updating ... to version 9" is meaningless as there are 9.1, 9.2, and 9.3.  Your code compiles with 7.5, 8.3.1 (development version of 8.4), 9.2.1 (development version of 9.3), and 10.0.0.

Comment: @evets In my experience most regressions are bound to major versions. That's why the bugzilla also uses markings like `[9,10 Regression]` which appears to be the case here as well.

Comment: Does not compile with my 9.3.1 and 10.1.1 FWIW. Good opportunity to check what bugs my main production code will encounter with 10. Usually going to a new major version hits one or two bugs.

Comment: @evets I am using version 9.3.0, available via the Ubuntu testing toolchain

Comment: @VladimirF, I'm well aware of the convention used in the subject line in GCC bugzilla.  There are also 'Known to work:' and 'Known to fail:' fields that give the specific version(s).  In SO, an apparently unofficial place to register gfortran bug reports, version 9 is meaningless.

Comment: @evets The point is that most regressions get introduced when introducing new features into new major versions. They could indeed be fixed in a later minor version, but if not, saying it is present on the 8,9,10 or 11 branch (e.g. nightly) is entirely enough. By not working on version 9 one means on the latest reasonably accessible build.

Comment: You're welcomed.  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94397

Comment: @francescalus thank you, that fixes the issue. Do you want to post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I new I have seen that before. Google is really bad at searching in the bugzilla.